# Give unique file names to multiple file download via CURL

Tags: xargs

I am running this:

```
cat Human_List.txt | xargs -I "%" curl -O http://www.pdb.org/pdb/files/"%".pdb
```

As you can see it is taking each file name from my Human_List.txt and looping it into the URL. As a save option I have -O where it takes the URL name and saving it using that line name from the Human_List.

WHAT I NEED is to save each one of those .pdb files with a Human_"foobar".pdb file name so I can differentiate between my different list downloads. Otherwise I cannot differentiate which one of downloads came from which list.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ while read LINE; 
    do curl -o Human_$LINE.pdb http://www.pdb.org/pdb/files/$LINE.pdb;
    done < Human_List.txt
```